# Envio de email masivos con phpmailer

Tags: email, phpmailer, godaddy

Buenas noches necesito enviar email masivos, mas o menos 2 mil cada dos dias. el problema es que son muchos para enviar a la vez y solo se envia una parte, unas veces sale error por exeso de tiempo cargando y no alcanza a enviarlos todos, otras veces no sale error, pero solo manda una parte como continuación, que puedo hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que GoDaddy te esté bloqueando tus correos por el envió masivo de ellos. GoDaddy maneja un servicio de Email Marketing que es probable que tengas que contratar u otro alternativo.

[image: Email Marketing]